# Humanoid not detecting speed in custom character Roblox lua

Tags: lua, model, roblox

I'm trying to make the model play a walking animation when it's moving. The problem is that the script is not detecting any movements but it is in fact moving. I want the model to be a playable character for the player but it just doesn't work. I made another model and tested it there too, that one worked just fine. I don't know what's wrong with I've been stuck on this problem for too long

the model: https://www.roblox.com/library/14294793342/mini

regular script:
`

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage") local CubeShiftEvent = RS:WaitForChild("CubeShiftEvent")

CubeShiftEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, model) local bull = true local oldModel = player.Character local newModel = model:Clone()
local oldCFrame = oldModel:GetPrimaryPartCFrame()

player.Character = newModel
newModel.Parent = workspace -- [1] this follows current character loading behavior
newModel:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(oldCFrame)
oldModel:Destroy()
print(player.Character.Name)
local moving = false
local idle = false
end)`

--player:LoadCharacter()
```

```
local scriptlocal RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")local CubeShiftEvent = RS:WaitForChild("CubeShiftEvent")local model = game.ReplicatedStorage.StarterCharacterlocal player = game.Players.LocalPlayerUIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input,gameProcessed)if not gameProcessed thenif input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard thenif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then--local newAv = model:Clone()--newAv.Parent = game.StarterPlayerCubeShiftEvent:FireServer(model)endendendend)
```

when i moved the Hroot part with my mouse it detected speed but it does not do with when im not moving manually